# NameError: name 'factor' is not defined EN PHYTON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un programa algo básico en phyton, pero no he logrado avanzar por un error que me genera.

El enunciado es el siguiente: *"Pregunta 1.1. Defina to_percentage en la celda de abajo. Llame a su función para convertir la proporción .2 en un porcentaje. Nombre ese porcentaje "veinte_porciento"."*

Adicional debo usar un estilo de plantilla de código, que es la siguiente ('...' significan que debería ir código ahí):

```
...
    """Convierte una proporción en un porcentaje."""
    factor = ...
    ...

veinte_porciento = ...
veinte_porciento
```

Este es mi programa:

```
def to_percentage(proporción,factor):
    """Convierte una proporción en un porcentaje."""
    factor = 100
    proporción = .2

veinte_porciento = proporción*factor
veinte_porciento
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5004/958604917.py in <module>
      4     proporción = .2
      5 
----> 6 veinte_porciento = proporción*factor
      7 veinte_porciento

NameError: name 'factor' is not defined
```

Les agradecería muchísimo si pueden ayudarme a encontrar y solucionar el error, recién estoy empezando en phyton y se me ha dificultado un montoon!

Comment: Si creas una variable dentro de una función, no puedes usar esa variable fuera de la función. Se llaman variables locales.

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder! es decir que, ¿el programa no se puede realizar con la plantilla definida? @DanteS.

Comment: El problema es la identacion. Si identas esas dos ultimas líneas, debería funcionar. Ya que así esas variables existirían por ser parte de la función `to_percentage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables que están dentro de la función, pertenecen al ámbito de la función, o sea, mueren al salir de ella.

Estás haciendo al revés el código, dentro de las funciones no se deben definir valores, a menos que sea algo inmutable. Las funciones se usan para ejecutar pedazos o partes del programa y al finalizar, el resultado puede ser retornado, o no, a donde fue llamada la función.

En otras palabras, la operación debe hacerse dentro de la función y el resultado debe ser retornado, así:

```
def to_percentage(proporcion):
    """Convierte una proporción en un porcentaje."""
    resultado = proporcion * 100
    return resultado

# ## El programa empieza aquí
proporcion = 0.2
veinte_porciento = to_percentage(proporcion) # Aqui se devuelve el resultado de la función
print(f'El porcentaje es: {veinte_porciento}%')
```

Puedes reutilizar esa función mandándole otros valores, por ejemplo:

```
ochenta_porciento = to_percentage(0.8)
print(ochenta_porciento) # Imprime: 80.0
```